# Is it possible to make hook_view() the same as hook_edit()?

Tags: 7, hooks

My current client does not like the separation between viewing their custom content types and having to travel to a different page to edit. They are pushing for the View page and the Edit page to be the same. Are there any negative ramifications of simply redirecting from `hook_view()` over to `hook_edit()`?

The client is a desktop application developer, with a large installed base of clients, and I'm making the first "web version" of their desktop software. They want their webapp to behave as close as possible to their last desktop version. Their application is sorta like a CAD/3D-Modeler, and "viewing a model" without the ability to make any edits makes no sense for their users. Hence the request to get rid of `hook_view()` and make `hook_edit()` triple functional (create,edit & view).

Comment: An implementation of `hook_view()` should not redirect the user to a different page; `hook_view()` and `hook_edit()` are not the menu callbacks for /node/%node/view and /node/%node/edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supposing that "model" is the content type you are referring, then I would use code similar to the following one.

```
function mymodule_menu_alter(&$items) {
  $items['node/%node']['title callback'] = 'mymodule_node_title'; 
  $items['node/%node']['title arguments'] = array('view', 1);
  $items['node/%node']['page callback'] = 'mymodule_node_page';
  $items['node/%node']['page arguments'] = array('view', 1);
  $items['node/%node']['access callback'] = 'mymodule_node_access';
  $items['node/%node']['access arguments'] = array('view', 1);
  $items['node/%node/edit']['title callback'] = 'node_node_title'; 
  $items['node/%node/edit']['title arguments'] = array('edit', 1); 
  $items['node/%node/edit']['page callback'] = 'mymodule_node_page';
  $items['node/%node/edit']['page arguments'] = array('edit', 1);
  $items['node/%node/edit']['access callback'] = 'mymodule_node_access'; 
  $items['node/%node/edit']['access arguments'] = array('edit', 1);
}

function mymodule_node_access($op, $node) {
  if ($node->type == 'model') {
    return ($op == 'view') ? node_access('edit', $node) : FALSE;
  }

  return node_access($op, $node);
}

function mymodule_node_page($op, $node) {
  if ($node->type == 'model') {
    return node_page_edit($node);
  }

  if ($op == 'edit') {
    return node_page_edit($node);
  }
  if ($op == 'view') {
    return node_page_view($node);
  }
}

function mymodule_node_title($node) {
  if ($node->type == 'model' || $op == 'view') {
    return node_page_title($node);
  }

  if ($op == 'edit') {
   return t('Edit');
  }
}
```

Using this code, the node edit form is always show accessing /node/%node, or /node%node/view for the "model" content type.

Comment: This is very interesting to me. I've not used hook_menu_alter() before, and this appears to be the perfect application. I see what you're doing, but wonder where I can read more about the structure of the core menu callbacks, such as what you are altering here in this example. Know of a good tutorial on core menu usage and the modification of its operation? This looks quite promising.

Comment: The documentation for [hook_menu()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--hooks--core.php/function/hook_menu/6) describes the value returned by that hook; [node_menu()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--node--node.module/function/node_menu/6) is the function that defines the menu callback used by Node.

Answer (score 1):

There is [a module](http://drupal.org/project/reviser) which in effect does the desired. At least I like it and want to mention it.

> Reviser is an inline wysiwyg editor, meaning you can edit the node body content without going to the edit page. Just click anywhere on the node body and start editing. Since you are actually editing the HTML DOM on the same page where the content is actually viewed all changes you make will appear exactly the same when you hit save. A true what-you-see-is-what-you-get experience that a wysiwyg editor should provide
>
> This really is finally a wysiwyg editor that you will want to use. There is no need to go between the edit and view pages to make sure everything looks right. Just edit away until it 100% correct, hit save and then you are done.

Comment: Very interesting... investigating. Thank you groovehunter.